# How do you change the name of the Bottom Line on the eguile Balance Sheet report?

Tags: gnucash

I like the layout of the report accessed through `Reports->Assets and Liabilities->Balance Sheet using eguile-gnc`. But I don't like that at the end of the report, after *Total Retained Earnings*, it says: **Imbalance Amount**.

I've done some investigating and found that this is actually always *Unrealized Gain* (or loss, depending.)

I decided to change the report so it says **Unrealized Gain/(Loss)** instead. How did I do that?

Notes:

1. This is not the built-in *Imbalance-USD* (or whatever your currency is) account. Not that.
2. Similarly, it's also not the *Orphan-USD* account.
3. It's not broken transactions. It *is* possible for transactions to be broken and cause things to be out of balance, but this is not what we're talking about here.

Answer (score 1):

This is for GNC 4.9, Build ID Flathub 4.9-1. So YMMV, but you can probably still find and change the file you need in the lengthy text below.

---

TL;DR: Find the file called `balsheet-eg.eguile.scm`, then edit this file to change `Imbalance Amount` to the label of your choice. I chose `Unrealized Gain/(Loss)`, for example.

---

Here are some suggestions for finding the file on a Linux system:

I found a file with *Imbalance Amount* in it at `/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.gnucash.GnuCash/x86_64/stable/*/files/share/guile/site/2.2/gnucash/reports/templates/balsheet-eg.eguile.scm`. There's a big, long hexadecimal number where the `*` appears in the path. I'm 99% certain that will be different for a each flatpak installation.

You can find the report on your system like this:

```
$ sudo find /var/lib -name balsheet-eg.eguile.scm
```

If you don't want to `sudo` (or can't), you could do this like this under the assumption that you have access to the file (but you can't change it without sudo, soooo....):

```
$ find /var/lib -name balsheet-eg.eguile.scm 2>/dev/null
```

It will help if you know approximately where to look; and `/var/lib` may not be where you're installed. The atomic option is to look from `/`, but that may take a very long time, depending on your system. You can also try looking here:

```
/opt
/lib
/home/you
```

Again, it depends heavily on your installation.

One final possibility: run `$ df` to get a list of filesystems on your system. Now run this command, substituting each "reasonable" filesystem for `$FS`.

```
$ sudo find $FS -mount -name balsheet-eg.eguile.scm
```

The term "reasonable" means *not* filesystems like `/data` or `/Videos`, etc.

The `-mount` option prevents find from descending past a mount point, so going out to search your NFS movie database doesn't happen.

Here are some filesystems to search: `/`, `/opt`, `/var`, `/home`. If you have multiple users, you might want to limit `/home` to just yourself and only do so if you're pretty sure you installed locally to your home directory (you'll know.)

Feeling nerdy? Use this instead:

```
$ for FS in / /var /var/lib /opt /usr /lib /usr/lib; do
> sudo find $FS -mount -name balsheet-eg.eguile.scm
> done
```

---

Once you find the file, make sure you make a copy of the un-mangled file. Then use your favorite editor to find the phrase `Imbalance Amount` in the file. Change it to whatever you think is more appropriate.

---

Caveat: if you upgrade, it's possible -- even likely -- that the upgrade will overwrite your changes. Just change it again. Note that saving the report through GNC only saves the report options. The underlying report, including this phrase we just changed, is not saved when you save a report. This also means that any report you have saved through `Reports->Save Report Configuration[ As...]` will have the new **Unrealized Gain/(Loss)** label when you run (or reload) it.

Finished product (uses other-than-default options in the report):
[image]